# Как получить данные устройства если оно используется системой?

Tags: linux

Как получить данные устройства на шине i2c (DS3231) из пространства пользователя, если оно используется системой (используется как основные аппаратные часы)? При попытке получить дамп регистров утилитой i2cdump получаю ошибку, и сообщение о том, что устройство занято. Это логично, но данные все же надо получить. Удалять , читать данные и добавлять в систему часы снова не вариант, данные надо довольно часто читать.

Comment: Зависит от драйвера и его пространства запуска (ядро или пространство пользователя). Если драйвер в ядре и имплементирован через regmap i2c API, то содержимое регистров можно получить через debugfs. Или у вас там не Linux?

Comment: Linux. Спасибо за направление, буду смотреть.

Comment: Я посмотрел, в текущем ядре драйвер написан с применением regmap API, так что в этом случае делать ничего не нужно — всё уже написано.

Comment: Судя по всему для ядра 4.х.х это будет работать, но в моем случае ядро 3.4. И обновить ядро до актуального сейчас невозможно.

Comment: i2cdump с флагом -f вроде нормально чиатет